Who first said "it is easy to sacrifice someone else's pawns"?
I'm sure I read this quote somewhere - presumably someone analyzing another player's games, and talking about some adventurous sacrifice which most people won't play. However, I don't remember who the player is and/or if they were quoting someone else. Searching for this phrase on Google returns no results either.
Does anyone know who first said this?

Could be Tartakower or someone paraphrasing him. "It’s always better to sacrifice your opponent’s men."

@emdio That was my first thought - I don't think it's Tartakower himself, the meaning is different from the famous quote, but it could well be a paraphrase

I think I found the source I read this in: Sam Shankland's annontation to game 9 of the 2021 World Chess Championship.
[FEN "r2qr1k1/ppp3pp/1bn1bp2/4p3/3P4/2P2NP1/PB2PPBP/R2Q1RK1 w - - 0 13"]


13...Na5 might be worth considering. Any Grunfeld player knows to abuse the c4-square in this structure. Still, it's of course easy to sacrifice other people's pawns and one cannot really fault Caruana for not wanting to allow dxe5 against a clearly prepared opponent.

Given the Tartakower quote in the comments, I imagine this was Shankland paraphrasing Tartakower.

. . . though sacrificing the your opponent's men is not the same as sacrificing the material of a player whose game you're annotating or kibitzing.

And around here (Oxford, UK) comments along the line in the question (rather than this answer) when analyzing were being made before 2021 - I personally think its just a meme in the chess player's zeitgeist, having evolved from the original Tartakower quote, and it could have evolved separately in many different geographical areas.

Shouldn't this have been edited into the question rather than posted as an answer ? Is it certainly not answering the question of "who said it first"..

@Evargalo assuming Shankland was paraphrasing Tartakower, and Tartakower's quote was well-known, then Shankland is presumably the first to say it (because he came up with it). If someone comes up with a better answer, I can accept that.

@Allure : When Shankland said it in 2021 it's definitely not the first occurence. I am sure to have heard "it is easier to sacrifice someone's else pawns/pieces" many many times at least since 2010, probably much earlier, both in chess online comment and in clubs or tournaments when analysing games. It is established as a common sentence in the chess world for a decade at the very least.
